# Sending BLOB to APEX RESTful service

Tags: javascript, oracle, rest, oracle-apex

I want to send a BLOB to an APEX RESTful service. The payload has to be a JSON (not form-data, I've had a lor of problems with that in the server side).

The BLOB is an image that I need to upload to the DB, my problem is that I don't know how to send the data in the payload. Should it be a string that represents the array of bytes? Should it be the array itself? (I managed to extract a binary string with the readASBinaryString method of javascipt's FileReader).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your BLOB data could be encoded to **Base64** and then transported in JSON document as a string. You can use window.btoa() to convert binary data to Base64 string.

For example:

```
{
    "data": "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="
}
```